# Put elements at Even position after elements at Odd position in a Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, partitioning, singly-linked-list, function-definition

The question is asking us to put elements at odd positions before elements at even position in a linked list.

Test Cases:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} --> {1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6}

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} --> {1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6}
```

My Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;

    node(int value)
    {
        data = value;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

void InsertAtHead(node *&head, int val)
{
    node *n = new node(val);

    n->next = head;
    head = n;
}

void InsertAtTail(node *&head, int val)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        InsertAtHead(head, val);
        return;
    }
    node *n = new node(val);

    node *temp = head;

    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = n;
}

void EvenOdd(node *&head)
{
    node *odd = head;
    node *even = head->next;
    node *evenStart = even;

    while (odd->next != NULL && even->next != NULL)
    {
        odd->next = even->next;
        odd = odd->next;
        even->next = odd->next;
        even = even->next;
    }
    if (odd->next == NULL)
    {
        even->next = NULL;
    }
    odd->next = evenStart;
}

void display(node *head)
{
    node *temp = head;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    node *head = NULL;

    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        InsertAtTail(head, a[i]);
    }
    display(head);

    EvenOdd(head);
    display(head);

    return 0;
}
```

This code will only work for even number of nodes in Linked List.
If we take odd number of nodes in a Linked List, then it will show segmentation fault.

For example: This code will work correctly for 1st test case.

But for second test case, it will show segmentation fault.

Comment: This is what [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) can do for you.

Comment: @acraig5075 Can you please explain it to me, I didn't get it.

Comment: In case you want to preserve order, it would be [std::stable_partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition).

Comment: Pen(cil) and paper is the best way to work out pointer-based code, both for creating and debugging.

Comment: @acraig5075 Can you send me code, or at least a hint, because my second test case is not working, and I don't understand how will std::stable_partition will work and where to use it in code.

Comment: @molbdnilo I know bro, but here my code is showing segmentation fault for a second test case. If you found the bug, please let me know.

Comment: @Jay1105 Why is the function named EvenOdd when you provided examples where odd numbers precede even numbers?

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)...

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It's just the name of the function, it doesn't matter, bro. By the way, got my answer just needed to add one more condition.

Comment: @Jay1105 You are mistaken. Your name of the function is only confusing readers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sorry for the function name. Actually, it was a tutorial file, and the professor made mistake. Sorry again for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you go into loop in `OddEven`, `odd` is 1 and `even` is 2.

```c
    while (odd->next != NULL && even->next != NULL)
    {
        odd->next = even->next;
        odd = odd->next;
        even->next = odd->next;
        even = even->next;
    }
```

After first loop, `odd` is 3 and `even` is 4. Next is `odd` is 5 and `even` is 6, then `odd` is 7 and `even` is `NULL`.

```c
    if (odd->next == NULL)
    {
        even->next = NULL;
    }
```

Since `even` is `NULL`, `even->next` becomes a problem and throw segmentation fault. You can just remove that part as whole.

Not related but take a look at [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework problem so I do not want to give the exact answer. You are heading in the correct direction in your `EvenOdd()` function with:

```
node *odd = head;
node *even = head->next;
node *evenStart = even;
```

However, start with:

```
node *odd = nullptr;
node *even = nullptr;
node *current = head;

while (current != nullptr)
{
    // partition into odd and even sets here

    current = current->next;
}

// put the first even-node pointer at the end of the odd partition
```

It might be a big learning curve but put your code at the top of a Visual Studio test library class or rewrite the source file as a [Googletest](https://google.github.io/googletest/primer.html) file. That way, you can execute both test patterns you identified in your question. Also:

1. What happens if the list contains an odd number of items?
2. What if it is an empty list?

From there, you can easily add more test cases and re-test your code.

Comment: Tried it out, but it doesn't work. It just provides the same linked list without modifications.

Comment: As I said, I do not want to give the actual code as an answer. However, what you are doing is 1) Removing an item from the front of the "current" list (which `next` pointer needs to be rewritten?); 2) deciding if that node belongs in the "odd" or "even" list; 3) appending the item to the tail of the correct list (which `next` pointer needs to be rewritten?). You are constantly rewriting the `next` pointers.

Comment: I think you didn't get the question. As you have said that if linked contains only odd numbers, see the question is asking us to put the elements at odd places (not the odd elements) first in the linked list then the elements at even places (not the even elements) . Hope you get it.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I have updated my answer to reflect you are partitioning the list based on original position within the input list. My previous comment still stands: an `if` statement decides whether to append to the "odd" list or the "even" list but the condition is based on position in the original list, not the value at the current node.

Answer (score 1):

My five cents.:)

For starters there is no any need to declare explicitly a constructor for the class node.

```
class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;

    node(int value)
    {
        data = value;
        next = NULL;
    }
};
```

Your life will be simpler if you will deal with an aggregate. For example

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
```

The function name `EvenOdd` is confusing because as it follows from your examples  you want rearrange the list such a way that nodes at odd positions would precede nodes at even positions and you are counting positions starting from 1.  So the function name should be at least `OddEven`. Otherwise if to start positions from 0 then the function name indeed should be `EvenOdd`.

The function initially can invoke undefined behavior because there is no check whether head is equal to `nullptr`. So there can be used a null pointer to access a memory for example in these statements

```
node *even = head->next;
```

and

```
while (odd->next != NULL && even->next != NULL)
```

Moreover it is not necessary that the list contains a sequence of nodes where nodes with odd values and even values alternate. For example try to run your function for a list that contains the following sequence of numbers `{ 1, 3, 2, 4, 5 }`.

I would write the program the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

void push_front( node * &head, int data  )
{
    head = new node { data, head };
}

void clear( node * &head )
{
    while ( head ) delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
}

std::ostream & display( node * &head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( const node *current = head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        os << current->data << ' ';
    }
    
    return os;
}

template <typename InputIterator>
void create( node * &head, InputIterator first, InputIterator last )
{
    clear( head );
    
    node **current = &head;
    
    for ( ; first != last; ++first )
    {
        *current = new node { *first, nullptr };
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }
}

node * EvenOdd( node * &head )
{
    node **odd = &head;
    node *even_head = nullptr;
    node **even = &even_head;
    
    size_t pos = 0;
    
    while ( *odd )
    {
        if ( pos++ % 2 != 0 )
        {
            *even = *odd;
            *odd = ( *odd )->next;
            ( *even )->next = nullptr;
            even = &( *even )->next;
        }
        else
        {
            odd = &( *odd )->next;
        }
    }
    
    *odd = even_head;
    
    return even_head;
}

int main() 
{
    node *head = nullptr;
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    
    create( head, std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );
    
    display( head ) << '\n';
    
    auto pos = EvenOdd( head );
    
    display( head ) << '\n';
    display( pos ) << '\n';
    
    clear( head );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7 9 
1 3 5 7 9
```

Comment: Appreciate your efforts, but the question is asking something else and your code is doing something else. The question is asking us to put the elements at odd places (not the odd elements) before the elements at even places (not even elements) . Hope you understood the question.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question in so far as it doesn't explain what is wrong with your attempt. If anyone answers that, then that'll be a better answer.

However this answer is more for your information how it'd be solved using the standard C++ library [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm), which is available to you and there's no shame in using.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    // a lambda function that tests whether a single number is odd
    auto is_odd = [](int i){ return i % 2 > 0; };

    // reorganise elements such that odd numbers are moved to the front, maintaining their original order (stable)
    std::stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), is_odd);

    // output elements (space delimited) to console 
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the number of elements in the lists is odd, the even pointer is pointing to NULL, making it impossible to access the next node of even during the while condition.
Try the following code and it will solve your issue.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node* next;

    node(int val){
        data = val;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

void insertAtTail(node* &head,int val){
    node* n = new node(val);

    if(head == NULL){
        head = n;
        return;
    }

    node* temp = head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL){
        temp=temp->next;
    }

    temp->next = n;

    return;
}

void display(node* &head){
    node* temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        cout<<temp->data;
        if(temp->next!=NULL){
            cout<<"->";
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    cout<<endl;

    return;
}

void evenAfterOdd(node* &head){
    node* odd = head;
    node* even = head->next;
    node* evenStart = even;

    while(odd->next!=NULL && even->next!=NULL){
        odd->next = even->next;
        odd = odd->next;
        even->next = odd->next;
        if(even->next!=NULL){
            even = even->next;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }

    odd->next = evenStart;

    return;
}

int main(){
    node* head = NULL;
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        insertAtTail(head,arr[i]);
    }

    display(head);

    evenAfterOdd(head);
    display(head);



    return 0;
}
```

Hope you find it helpful! :)

Answer (score -1):

Not answering your question, but suggesting an easier way to solve the problem.

You can also loop backwards over the linked list and move all odd numbers to the start of the list.

It would look something like this:

```
int main()
{
    node *head = NULL;

    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    for (int i = 7; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if(value == odd) {
            move to front of the list
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You **can't move backwords** over a singly linked list. You can add more details on **how to move all odd numbers to the start.** Also there is a **logical error** in your code. You need to use `>` instead of `<` in `for (int i = 7; i < 0; i--)`.